# Is republishing social meta tag's content permissible for commercial use?

Tags: copyright, internet, licensing, public-domain

Is it legal to do the following (which **Facebook** and **Twitter** do for **commercial use**): embed [social meta tag](http://www.bruceclay.com/blog/how-to-use-social-meta-tags/)'s public content (such as pictures) on a website for commercial use, linking back to the source and not claiming ownership of the external content?

Is this protected by [fair use](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/fair-use-rule-copyright-material-30100.html) or something similar?

Comment: Related: http://law.stackexchange.com/q/762/10

Comment: Offhand, I'm wondering if this is akin to press releases.